How to smooth out edge curves in blender
I have this curved geometry made up of edges, if I wanted to smooth out this curve to make it consistent instead of wobbly like it is how would I do that?




you have intermediate edges that tend to flatten the faces, first thing try a X > Limited Dissolve, give a Subdivision Surface modifier to your object and see what it gives, if it is still not good please share your file

@moonboots That method isn't consistent enough to help + there are too many edges to take care of. I unsubdivided the geometry which helped make it less complicated but it's still not a smooth curve. Subsurface ruins the entire geometry. I've uploaded the file to the question.

Right click > Shade Smooth then give it a Normals > Smooth by Angle modifier, it will smooth the shading, not the general shape, if you want to round the shape try a right click > LoopTools > Relax for example, increase the Iteration in the Opeartor Box

Using looptools did work nicely, but with some side effects (weird mesh artifacts). What part of the mesh would you recommend selecting to use the relax tool on?
Edit: playing around with it a bit makes it work flawlessly. Thanks for the suggestion, definitely an addon to keep in my arsenal.

You have intermediate edges that tends to flatten the faces, first thing in Edit mode do a X > Limited Dissolve to remove these edges. Then right click > Shade Smooth to smooth the shading, and give it a Normals > Smooth by Angle modifier to prevent the smooth shading between the perpendicular faces. To smooth the shape itself select the edges in Edit mode and right click > LoopTools > Relax, increase the Iteration in the Operator Box:

